# Add Points shp attributes to Polygon shp by Point location (as Spatial Join in ArcGIS)

Tags: r, spatial-join, voronoi-thiessen

I have a set of points in .shp (ESRI, available here: http://ulozto.cz/xGqRVFrR/voronoi-zip). I would like to calculate Voronoi tesselation from the points, thus create polygons. So far, so good. However, **points attribute table is not transferred automatically in R to Voronoi tesselation polygons during calculation** (as is the case in ArcGIS).

Thus, depending points' spatial location I want to add points' attributes to my new Voronoi's polygons. I tried to used function

```
over(diagram.poly, bod.sp)
```

but it creates data.frame, not polygon.

Please,

1. **how to automatically add points' attributes to Voronoi polygon** OR
2. **how to use resulting data.frame as my polygon's attribute table?**

I'm sure it is pretty trivial task but I still can't find my answer!

my code:

```
# exemple with my data
library(spatstat)
library(sp)
library(deldir)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

# set directory
wd<- setwd("C:/Users/***/voronoi")

# read point shp, considered as SpatialPointsDataFrame
bod<-readOGR(dsn=setwd("C:/Users/***/voronoi"), layer="voronoi_tess")

# convert firstly to ppp (Spatial point pattern (object of class "ppp")
bod.ppp<-as.ppp(bod)

# calculate Voronoi tesselation
diagram<-dirichlet(bod.ppp)

# convert diagram to SpatialPolygon
diagram.poly=as(diagram, "SpatialPolygons")

# use CRS from "bod"
proj=CRS(proj4string(bod))

# define diagram CRS
proj4string(diagram.poly)=proj

# check if projections are identical
identical(proj4string(bod), proj4string(diagram.poly))

# plot the result
plot(diagram.poly, border = "darkgrey")
points(bod, col = "red", pch = 16)

# try to apply over{sp} function, producing data.frame
over(diagram.poly, bod)
```

[image: Voronoi tesselation from red points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I post my answer:

I missed out how to convert **SpatialPolygon** to **SpatialPolygonDataFrame** and difference between them. SpatialPolygon doesn't contain attribute table, SpatialPolygonDataFrame does. So attribute table can be easily add from my points attribute table. No need to use **over** function :-D

```
# re-written code
library(sp)
library(deldir)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)

# set directory
wd<- setwd("C:/Users/***/voronoi")

# read point shp, considered as SpatialPointsDataFrame
bod<-readOGR(dsn=setwd("C:/Users/***/voronoi"), layer="voronoi_tess")

# convert firstly to ppp (Spatial point pattern (object of class "ppp")
bod.ppp<-as.ppp(bod)

# calculate voronoi tesselation
diagram<-dirichlet(bod.ppp)

# convert diagram to SpatialPolygon - without attribute table
diagram.poly=as(diagram, "SpatialPolygons")

# create attribute table from points shp (bod), as data frame
att.bod<-as.data.frame(bod)

# convert it to SpatialPolygonDataFrame - include SpatialPolygon + attribute table (att.bod)
s_poly <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(diagram.poly, att.bod)

# export to ArcGIS to verify attributes
writeOGR(s_poly, wd, "s_poly", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```